# Maven surefire plugin not picking tests in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, cucumber, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

My tests are running in eclipse, mvn test, command line also but not in jenkins. maven surefire plugin in console says no test to run. I suspect maven surefire plugin not able to pick tests. my POM looks like :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>groupid</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactiddemo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Jenkins job logs:

```
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Second_Job\pom.xml verify -Dcucumber.options=test/features/FirstDemo.feature -DskipTests=false
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< groupid:artifactiddemo >-----------------------
[INFO] Building artifactiddemo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ artifactiddemo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Second_Job\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ artifactiddemo ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ artifactiddemo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Second_Job\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ artifactiddemo ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.8.1:test (default-test) @ artifactiddemo ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Second_Job\target\surefire-reports
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I know I am missing on something to include testsin surefire plugin thing .. but they are running smoth on local eclipse or mvn test command. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check and ensure that you have test classes inside test folder, are you able to run locally ?

Comment: I have very similar issue. Locally it runs with no issues, but in Jenkins agent it does not see tests. Did you found the root cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide any information about your test classes. Make sure that the class names of your tests match one of these [patterns](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html):

- "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
- "**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
- "**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests".
- "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".

Comment: If they were able to run the tests with `mvn test`, this couldn't have been the problem...